# Compact command not freeing up space in MongoDB 2.0

Tags: mongodb

I just installed MongoDB 2.0 and tried to run the compact command instead of the repair command in earlier versions. My database is empty at the moment, meaning there is only one collection with 0 entries and the two system collections (indices, users). Currently the db takes about 4 GB of space on the harddisk. The db is used as a temp queue with all items being removes after they have been processed.

I tried to run the following in the mongo shell.

```
use mydb
db.theOnlyCollection.runCommand("compact")
```

It returns with

```
ok: 1
```

But still the same space is taken on the harddisk. I tried to compact the system collections as well, but this did not work.

When I run the normal repair command

```
db.repairDatabase()
```

the database is compacted and only takes 400 MB.

Anyone has an idea why the compact command is not working?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Best

Alex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Collection compaction is not supposed to decrease the size of data files. Main point is to defragment collection and index data - combine unused space gaps into continuous space allowing new data to be stored there. Moreover it may actually *increase* the size of data files:

> Compaction may increase the total size of your data files by up to 2GB. Even in this case, total collection storage space will decrease.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/compact+Command#compactCommand-Effectsofacompaction

Comment: Thanks, I understood that. But in my case there are about 6 datafiles for the db in the data directory with increasing sizes (64 MB, 128 MB, ..., 2 GB). However, the database is empty so shouldn't the compact command remove some of these files as they are no longer needed? What I saw in the docs is that they say that you don't need repair anymore now where journaling is on by default. But if repair is the only way to really compact the files?

Comment: @Alex I think the reason why it can't (or doesn't attempt to) remove data files when compacting a collection is that there can be other collections keeping data scattered around the data files. So the repair is the only option and it should be pretty fast on empty database.

Comment: Thanks again. Yes, it is pretty fast for empty databases. Just thought from the comments on the mongodb website that there is no need to use repair anymore. But thanks for the clarification.